# Getting data into js program through parameter or by reading Joomla URL of calling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

This seems a dumb question but as a new JS programmer I can't find a way to do this.  I can pass parameters to functions but cannot see how to pass a parameter to a program.

I have a JS program called from within a Joomla module.  The program uses AJAX to get data from an XML file, manipulate it and then output it to HTML through a jQuery call of:

```
jQuery('#eventsContent').append(htmlEvents.join(''));`
```

where, in the HTML I have: "

```
<div id="eventsContent"></div>
```

Depending on what page I am on in a Joomla module (or which module I am calling the program from), I want to set a variable within the JS program which tell me how to filter the data.  My reference, within the module to the program is simply in the program declaration of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="program_name.js"></script>
```

Is there some way I can append my parameter there and then access it in the program?

Even better yet for me as it would then be a single module, is there a way the program can read the current page from the URL.  From it, I could derive the variable value.

Can this be done one way or another?

Comment: What are you classing as a programme? An external script of functions?

Comment: have full access to url using `window.location` which has numerous properties. Provide example of what you want to derive from url